# How do I know If client wants to send the data or recieve the data from server

Tags: java, json, sockets

when I am trying to send the data from the server, my client side is not able to receive the data. The server is able to write the data to the JSON file. I think because I am executing the code for sending and receiving the data on the server inside the main method every time regardless of what request I am receiving from the client. Is there any built-in method in Java that helps us know what the client request is and execute the codes on the server depending on the request rather than executing the code for both read and write request. I hope You guys understand.

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(666);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("MYJSON.json");
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

  while(true) {
     Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new 
      InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
      String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
      writeJson(str); 

        String str;
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new
        OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        str = buff.readLine();
        printWriter.write(str);
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();

     }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand so I can only say that you need to read data sent (as request) by the client to know what the request is. For a server usual order is to receive request from client until the request is complete, process it and then answer it.

Comment: What he said.  Think of Apache or Tomcat and dealing with POST or GET - same concept, just your own implementation in non-http (or I guess you could implement needed parts of the http protocol)